# How to update Ember.Route model dynamically?

Tags: ember.js

I have a route like this:

```
App.PeopleRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function()
  {
    return App.Persons.find(personId);
  }
});
```

where personId is loaded asynchronically and is a normal JavaScript variable outside Ember. Now when route is displayed it gets the current PersonId and displays proper data. But when i change the value of personId it does not update the view.

So my question is what is a way to refresh this route to find records with new personId?

Comment: I could probably find a way to do this but before I do, could you tell me why you want to do this? You might be trying to do something that would be easier done in Ember.js way.

Comment: @tarasm is right, if you find yourself fighting the framework to do what it doesn't out of the the box then you should rethink your approach, because there is surely a better way to achieve what you need. Try to describe your use case more in detail and I'm sure we can help you out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `model` hook is executed only when entered via URL for routes with dynamic segments. Read more about it [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_model).

The easiest solution for this would be to use `transitionTo`.

```
App.PeopleRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params)
  {
    return App.Persons.find(params.personId);
  },
  actions: {
    personChanged: function(person){
       this.transitionTo("people", person);
    }
  } 
});

App.PeopleController = Em.Controller.extend({
  observeID: function(){
     this.send("personChanged");
  }.observes("model.id");
});
```

Comment: I tried this solution but this will not work. The transition happens but model stays same.